# Sorting a text file & removing duplicates

Tags: sorting, text-files

I have a large text file with 4-digit codes and some information about them in every row. It looks something like this:

```
3456 information
1234 info
2222 Some ohter info
```

I need to sort this file, so the codes are in ascending order in the file. Also, some codes appear more than once, so I need to remove duplicates. Can I do this with perl, awk or some other scripting language?

Thanks in advance,

-skazhy

Comment: To help you get started faster, what tools do you already have at your disposal? For example, you can quickly do this in MS Excel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sort happybirthday.txt | uniq
```

From [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tiptex6.html).

1st result for Google: `unix remove duplicate lines`.

Comment: Output the result to a new file : `sort happybirthday.txt | uniq > happybirthday_sorted.txt`

Comment: `sort -u` incorporates `uniq` and will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hash then read the file in line by line and for each line

- split at the first space
- check if the val(0), the number that you just split, is in the hash
- if not the insert the val(1), rest of the line, into the hash with a key val(0)
- continue

Then print the (sorted) hash to the file.